# Selecting number of form controls

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In my Angular app. I am combining two form groups to form one form group. I want to select only specific form controls from both the form groups.

I am using this method to combine two Form Groups.

```
this.thirdform = {...this.firstFormGroup.value, ...this.secondFormGroup.value }
```

Is there any possibility to choose the specific controls from the FormGroups. Please guide me. thanks in Advance.

Comment: That piece of code is not a [mcve], also does that even create a working `thirdform`? I find it hard to believe if you are using for example `FormGroup`, but then again, just guessing here...

Comment: You should do something like 
   `this.thirdform =new FormGroup({firstForm:this. firstFormGroup,secondForm:this. secondFormGroup})`

Comment: Hi @AJT_82,I am able to combine two FormGroups. i am unable to select the specific form controls from the FormGroups.

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve], best would be to create a stackblitz for your code. That one line of code says nothing to us.

Comment: `FormGroup.get('control-name')` returns controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable the controls that you don't want the formgroup.value will return only the ones you need. once you combine you can enable them again.

```
firstFormGroup.get('formControlYouDontwant').disable();
firstFormGroup.get('2ndformControlYouDontwant').disable();
secondFormGroup.get('formControlYouDontwant').disable();
secondFormGroup.get('2ndformControlYouDontwant').disable();

this.thirdform = {...this.firstFormGroup.value, ...this.secondFormGroup.value }

firstFormGroup.get('formControlYouDontwant').enable();
firstFormGroup.get('2ndformControlYouDontwant').enable();
secondFormGroup.get('formControlYouDontwant').enable();
secondFormGroup.get('2ndformControlYouDontwant').enable();
```

or you could just create new by getting the controls you want.

```
  this.thirdform = { 
    'controlName': this.firstFormGroup.get('controlyouWant').value, 
    '2ndcontrolName':this.firstFormGroup.get('controlyouWant').value, 
    '3rdcontrolName':this.firstFormGroup.get('controlyouWant').value, 
    '4thcontrolName': this.secondFormGroup.get('controlyouWant').value,
    '5thcontrolName': this.secondFormGroup.get('controlyouWant').value,
    '6thcontrolName': this.secondFormGroup.get('controlyouWant').value,
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using something like below.

```
thirdForm:FormGroup;
createForm() {
   this.thirdForm = new FormGroup({
    firstForm: new FormGroup({
     controlName: new FormControl()
    }),
    secondForm: new FormGroup({
      controlName: new FormControl()
     })
    });
}

getSpecificValue() {
   const specificValueFromFirstForm= this.thirdForm.get('firstForm').get('controlName');
   const specificValueFromSecondForm= this.thirdForm.get('secondForm').get('controlName');
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: From where did you come up with the fields `firstForm` and `secondForm`?

Comment: from the comment what you gave

Comment: In that case, you should also mention in the answer that the third form should be constructed differently.

Comment: yeah, I mentioned it now